# How to ensure csv file doesn't get overloaded with the same values

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

A bit stuck on how to go about this. I need to write the item and check to my csv file. But the code will be continuously running every hour or so and cannot add duplicate entries into the file. How can I go about ensuring this does not happen?

Table:

```
----------
Item | QTY
----------
sugar  | 14
mango  | 10
apple  | 50
berry  | 1
```

code:

```
  read_cursor = conn.cursor()
    read_cursor.execute("select item, check from items where check=0")

       with open('quantity_checker.csv', "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['item', 'check'])
        writer.writerows(read_cursor)
```

So what would currently happen is each time I run the code the csv file keeps adding the same values that I have selected in read_cursor. I need to be able to ensure that if the code does run again that it does not keep adding the same values into the csv file, or read the csv file retrieve the values and compare them before overwriting. A bit stuck......

Comment: Maybe: read all items, compare with what needs to be added and then only add what is not already in the file.

Comment: As long as you don't expect a **massive** amount of records (500k+) - I'd recommend to keep it simple and just clear the file and write everything on each dump.

Comment: @dahrens I can't overwrite the values in the file.

Comment: @Sam you are opening the file in write mode which means it _is_ already  truncated (cleared, overwritten, however you name it) on each call.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes you are correct, the problem was in the other method I was creating. Which was just inserting duplicate values into the db, I've now changed the db so it allows only unique values to be inserted. Thanks for that :)